# Can't get this selenium web driver to wait. but I can get it to sleep why?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Been struggling on this for a little while now and I'm pulling my hairout. Why does the 1st code not work? But second one does?

```
'''from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/jackrossanderson/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.url.Iwanttoscrape.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('searchbar')
search.send_keys("hometown")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Class_Name, 'button i want to click'))
    )
    element.click()

    driver.back()
except:
    print(error)'''

'''from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/jackrossanderson/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.urlIwanttoscrape')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('searchbar')
search.send_keys("home town")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(12)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button I want to press')

element.click()
driver.back()'''
```

I know the second way is frowned upon but I cant see why the top one doesnt work?

Comment: What is wrong with first code? Does the exception is thrown or something else?

Comment: Remove ''' from your code since it looks as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using 
 `element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "button i want to click")))` to make the driver wait and click based on the class name

Use, `element_to_be_clickable` is recommended as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)  because, `presence_of_element_located` description defines that it does not necessarily mean the element is visible or clickable.

Also, check the casing for `By.CLASS_NAME` used.